# Split string by . but ignore whats inside []

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string:

```
s='articles[zone.id=1].comments[user.status=active].user'
```

Looking to split (via `split(some_regex_here)`). The split needs to occur on every period other than those inside the bracketed substring.

Expected output:

```
["articles[zone.id=1]", "comments[user.status=active]", "user"]
```

How would I go about this? Or is there something else besides `split()`, I should be looking at?

Comment: Sure. Thought the title included these details already. I added more details in the body too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
s.split(/\.(?![^\[]*\])/)
```

I got this result,

```
2.3.2 :061 > s.split(/\.(?![^\[]*\])/)
=> ["articles[zone.id=1]", "comments[user.status=active]", "user"]
```

You can also test it here:
https://rubular.com/r/LaxEFQZJ0ygA3j

Comment: Nicely done!... It assumes brackets are matched, which is perfectly reasonable. It doesn't work if brackets can be nested, but the OP hasn't mentioned that as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is to split on periods that are not within matching brackets.

Here is a non-regex solution that works with any number of nested brackets. I've assumed the brackets are all matched, but it would not be difficult to check that.

```
def split_it(s)
  left_brackets = 0
  s.each_char.with_object(['']) do |c,a|
    if c == '.' && left_brackets.zero?
      a << '' unless a.last.empty?
    else
      case c
      when ']' then left_brackets -= 1
      when '[' then left_brackets += 1
      end
      a.last << c
    end
  end.tap { |a| a.pop if a.last.empty? }
end

split_it '.articles[zone.id=[user.loc=1]].comments[user.status=active].user'
  #=> ["articles[zone.id=[user.loc=1]]", "comments[user.status=active]", "user"]
```